# Snowflake SQL - How to get count of records grouped by week for the last n weeks

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to records in a table on a per week basis and using this [link](https://mindmajix.com/how-to-group-by-time-in-snowflake) as a reference on how to group by time in Snowflake SQL:

```
select COUNT(table_id), DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', DATEADD(Day, -49, CURRENT_DATE))
FROM data_warehouse_source
GROUP BY 2
```

I basically want to get the count of records for each of last say 7 weeks(hence 49 days above and using the DATEADD function to help me get the data from the last 7 weeks onwards up to the current date).

I'm not sure what I'm missing in the above query. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Which is your date field in the table? You used current date in the function. You should use the date attribute from your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a date column you can get the count for last 7 weeks / 49 days like below.

```
select 
    COUNT(1), 
    DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', "Date_Column") // Week("Date_Column") can also be used to get week of the year
from 
    Table
where 
    "Date_Column" > DATEADD(day,-49,date_trunc('day', current_date))
group by 2;
```

Comment: Thank you @abishek :). The date column is event_tstamp and its epoch time so I have to use to_timestamp(event_timestamp). If I may, I had a question:
1. Why should it be 'month' here:  'date_trunc('month', current_date)' instead of per 'week': date_trunc('week', current_date)
2. Even though I specify 49 days, it gives me the records of the last 12 weeks. Getting records of last 12 weeks is also ok for me because I can use the limit function to change how many entries I want in the result. I'm just wondering what is the significance of '49' in the above query if I'm getting 12 weeks data?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should be 'day' not 'month' . Also you can use Week(date_column) in the select if you would like to see just the week number of the year.

Comment: Thank you very much Abishek :) I also was experimenting with the above query a little further and I realised if I remove the where clause above, it will get me the last n weeks data and then I can use the limit clause. It felt that this way the query could be simplified further, right?